# qt: can I add option menu at qmenu like maya

Tags: qt, maya, optionmenu

[image: maya menu example]

I work on creating a tool for maya with pyqt4.
And in my tool, there is some menus on QMenuBar.
In that situation, I hope to create a menu + option menu style like above image.
As you see there is "New Scene" menu and square icon at the right side of "New Scene".
If I select just "New Scene", it works as creating a new scene.
And if I select square icon of "New Scene", it pops up option window for creating a new scene.
That's the one I hope to do.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from `QWidgetAction` ([docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidgetaction.html#details)) to create a widget that is basically a blend of a `QLabel` and a `QPushButton`.  *Note* You'll probably have to subclass `QLabel` in order to provide a rollover effect in terms of `QStyle`.